ZK-STARK's/FRI provable security reduction?
What is considered the peer reviewed security status of ZK-STARK's / FRI-protocol ?
The security is advertised to be reducible to a cryptographic hash function, has that been confirmed by multiple unrelated experts in that field? Has it been proven that in order to forge a proof the cryptographic hash function must be broken?
Regarding the zero-knowledge aspect of the system, has it been proven to be information theoretically secure? That is, there is no information to recover? (breaking the hash function may of course allow recovery through a different vector)
